# "Printers" menu doesn't exist in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, printing

I want to print in Xubuntu.  According to [this site,](https://docs.xubuntu.org/1710/user/C/printing-scanning.html) I should be able to go into settings manager, and go to the printers menu.  This is where the line of reasoning falls apart, because the printers menu doesn't exist.  How can I get it to exist?

Comment: Which Xubuntu release?

Comment: As far as I know, 18.

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to do `sudo apt install system-config-printer`